# PHP login using Ion Auth and Facebook login works locally on MAMP but not Web Server

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, ion-auth

The problem I'm facing is that manual new user subscription works locally but does not work on remote web server. The only difference between the non-working one and the one that works is that I upgraded Ion Auth to version 2 and added Facebook-Ion Auth library for Facebook Login.

Again, it works perfect locally, but not on the web server. PHP versions have been tested and work fine.

Here's the controller it gets stuck on (shows a blank page or goes back to homepage).

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Signup extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('forms/signupform');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters(
                        $this->config->item('error_start_delimiter', 'ion_auth'),
                        $this->config->item('error_end_delimiter', 'ion_auth')
                );
    }
    /**
     * @signup page of freelancer
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $data['title']  = lang('title_registration');
        $data['bodyclass'] = 'hold-transition register-page';
        $data['js_bottom_files'] = array('plugins/iCheck/icheck.min', 'js/custom');
        $data['cssfiles'] = array('plugins/iCheck/square/blue');

        // POST SIGNUP FORM
        if ('POST' == $this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD')  && $this->input->post('registersubmit') ) {
            // Signup Action
            $data['message_success'] = $this->signup();
        }

        // $user['checked'] = '';
        // if ($this->input->post('agree') == 'yes') {
        //  $user['checked'] = 'checked';
        // }

        $data['form'] = $this->signupform->view($user);

        //Render Or redirect according to User AccessLevel
        if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
            $this->template->load('layout', 'home', $data);
        } elseif ($this->ion_auth->is_admin()) {
            redirect(site_url('admin/dashboard'), 'refresh');
        } elseif ($this->ion_auth->is_members()) {
            redirect(site_url('note/create'), 'refresh');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @Signup action for user
     */
    public function signup()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
        // $this->form_validation->set_rules('full_name', lang('label_full_name'), 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('loginPassword', lang('label_signup_createpassword'), 'required|min_length['.$this->config->item('min_password_length', 'ion_auth').']|max_length['.$this->config->item('max_password_length', 'ion_auth').']');
        // $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmpassword', lang('label_signup_confirmpassword'), 'required');
        // $this->form_validation->set_rules('agree', 'Agree', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
            $email    = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = $this->input->post('loginPassword');

            // $additional_data = array('first_name' => $this->input->post('full_name'), 'school' => $this->input->post('school_name'));

            $group_ids = array( 'user_groups' => 2);

            if ($this->ion_auth->register($email, $password, $email, $additional_data, $group_ids)) {
                //check to see if we are creating the user
                //$this->session->set_flashdata('message_success', $this->ion_auth->messages());
                //redirect(site_url('/'), 'refresh');
                if($this->ion_auth->login($email, $password)){
                    redirect(site_url('note/create'), 'refresh');
                }
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message_error', $this->ion_auth->errors());
                redirect(site_url('/'), 'refresh');
            }
        }
    }
}

/* End of file signup.php */
```

Comment: Probably not the issue but you should remove `$this->CI =& get_instance();` from the controller constructor.

Comment: "Not Working" and "Gets Stuck" means what exactly? What is the line of code it's getting "stuck" on?

Comment: I'm confused, you say it works locally and not remotely and then you say the non-working one is essentially different in every way to the local one because you upgraded the entire system?

Comment: This ought to be a lesson for you. Develop on a server that matches the production environment as much as possible. Push changes to production from your develop branch, not just change code here and there and expect things to work. You don't have any idea what is going on, which is a bad place to be. Learn from this, because we probably can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially not the issue without more information but:

`$group_ids = array( 'user_groups' => 2);` should just be `$group_ids = array('2')`

See usage of the register function [here](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/).

and in the Ion auth config file `$config['identity']` should be set as email (if you haven't done so already).